# Which Version of the CF should I install on which Emulator, and how?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, emulation, entry-point

In trying to determine why my Windows CE Compact Framework app will compile but won't run on my devices, I've put breakpoints and MessageBox.Show()s in the app's entry point:

```
public static int Main(string [] args)
```

But there is no break at my breakpoints, and my MessageBox.Show()s are never shown.

I don't even get to that point using an emulator; using the "Windows Mobile 6 Classic" emulator, I get:

*"An unexpected error has occurred in HHS.exe.
Select Quit and then restart this program, or select Details for more information.
This application requires a newer version of the Microsoft(R) .NET Compact Framework than the version installed on this device."*

So how can I install a newer version of the CF on the emulator?

Or should I be using a different emulator? Is another one more suitable for my situation? - the actual devices being targeted are Symbol/Motorola 3[0,1]90s, one with CE 5 + CF 1, the other with CE 6 + CF 3.5

All of the available emulators from the project's "Target Device" dropdown are:

```
Pocket PC 2003 SE Emulator
Pocket PC 2003 SE Square Emulator
Pocket PC 2003 SE Square VGA Emulator
Pocket PC 2003 SE VGA Emulator

USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator
USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Square Emulator
USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Smartphone R2 QVGA Emulator

Windows Mobile 6 Classic Emulator <= I was using this one
Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator
Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square Emulator
Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square QVGA Emulator
Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square VGA Emulator
Windows Mobile 6 Professional VGA Emulator
```

### UPDATE

Copying the new build of the .exe to the device itself and running it, I *do* see the first MessageBox.Show() but not the subsequent one, so I added some more after the first and before the last. Attempting to copy the new .exe over to the device, though, I get:

[image]

And yet this is bogus: the device is not unresponsive (I can run other apps on it), neither is it disconnected - I warm-booted it once, tried again, and got the same err msg, then re-seated it and tried again, but still the same err msg.

I am more frustrated than a one-legged man in a butt-kicking contest.

### UPDATE 2

Even after swapping out the offending device for the other, running the app (older verison) from there, and then swapping them out again, as well as rebooting my PC (and thus reconnecting the PC<==>handheld connection "afresh") I get the same err msg/dialog!?!

The same is true for trying to delete a file there - it says it can't do it ("the device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected") <= neither is the case.

### UPDATE 3

Also bizarre (to me) is that when deploying to the emulator my breakpoints are not hit - doesn't the IDE have a connection with the Emulator?

Comment: So you can't just create a new CF app, put in a break point, hit F5 (in a Debug configuration) and have it stop at that break point?  Your dev environment sounds suspect.  I do this all day long. Admittedly I very rarely use the emulator, but I know that it works too.

Comment: Agreed.  Especially with CE devices since there is not a suitable emulator after CE 4.2, you really need to be stepping into your code on the devices.  I suggest setting up a scratch PC, installing VS and the SDKs and seeing if you can debug into a simple HelloWorld app.

Comment: No, breakpoints are never hit; they never have been, nor for the cat who used to be here who created this whole mess, I mean...whatever. The "on the devices" part is the problem - I can connect the PC to the devices, but never has there been a VS => Device connection.